# Removing a string from vector<string> at index defined in vector<int>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, erase

I would like to delete items of a vector of strings based on indexes from an integer vector.

The loop crashes, even though I can compile the code just fine.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector<string> s = { "foo", "bar", "random_word" };
    vector<int> i = { 0, 1 };
    for (int n = 0; n < i.size(); ++n)
    {
        s.erase(s.begin() + i[n]);
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the actual code that caused the problem:

```
// The vector in which the elements to be deleted are defined consists of
// { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 }.
//The identifier is i.
// The other vector consists of 
// { "Bancheri", "Bertagna", "Buzzoni", "Canepa", "De Vita", "Di Bella", 
// "Drago", "Esposito", "Fossati", "Francini", "Frontini", "Lorenzi", 
// "Marusceac", "Miscio", "Padovani", "Scarfo'", "Sieni", "Thea Cioni", 
// "Zunino" } and its identifier is s.
for (int p = 0; p < i.size(); ++p)
{
        s.erase(s.begin() + s[i])
}

// This is how I fixed it:
for (int r = i.size() - 1; r > 0; --r)
{
    s.erase(s.begin() + i[r]);
}
```

As you can see, I simply made an other loop which goes in reverse.

Comment: You should remove from bigger index to lower one.

Comment: @Rakete1111 yes, fixed it now

Comment: You don't initialize `n` ?

Comment: Note that a string at index `1` before `s[0]` is erased is different from the string at index `1` afterwards. Which of them do you want erased?

Comment: `for (int n; n < i.size(); n++)`- there is *NO* guarantee that `n` will be automatically set to `0`. You should do `for (int n = 0; n < i.size(); n++)`. Notice the initialization in the first statement

Comment: @Fureeish   my previous comment is also for you

Comment: The current code is correct. I can only guess based on the comments that this is not actually your real code. To get help with debugging you have to post real code that shows the problem. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think that closing this question as offtopic was incorrect, because the question contained a description of the problem, but it was hidden in one of the comments inside the code. Edited and voted to re-open.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The code as currently given works (at least for me), it leaves only the value "bar" in s, as expected, so the problem must be somewhere else, in code not shown. Keeping this closed until the OP comes up with the actual code and the actual error message.

Comment: @MrLister I wanted to remain with random_word, not bar. This doesn't crash (I didn't know at the time) simply because even after deleting 0, there is a value at index 1. In my actual code, I had 19 values, and I was trying to remove in ascending indexes. For example, I would remove everything from 0 to 10, remaining with 9 values, and then try to remove 10. That's where the program crashed. Now it's fixed, because in my actual code I delete the indexes in a descending order. Now that it's explained, can you take the closed flag off this post please?

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni Is it too much to ask to put the code in the question that actually causes the problem?

Comment: @MrLister Addded it.

Comment: @MrLister Hey I added it, can you revoke the -1 now please?

Comment: The downvote is not mine.

Comment: @MrLister Oh ok sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that once an item at `i[n]` is deleted, all indexes behind it shift back by one.

In order for this program to work, sort `i`, and iterate from largest to smallest.

Comment: Exactly. `std::sort(i.begin(), i.end(), std::greater<int>());` before entering the loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have no idea what that code means

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni It sorts the container in descending order.

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni If it isn't already sorted, that will sort descending (largest to smallest). You don't *have* to do that if you *know* it is already sorted (either ascending or descending). Just enumerate by iterator using `i.begin()` and `i.end()`, or `i.rbegin()` and `i.rend()` once sorted descending, or ascending, respectively. All of the above are worth investigating on  [cppreference](http://www.cppreference.com).

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out, the reason for crashing is the index invalidation - all the indexes that are greater than `i[n]` have to be decremented by 1 after deleting `i[n]`'th element.

By traversing the container of indexes in descending order, you make sure that there is no index greater than `i[n]` at any moment and therefore there is no need to tweak other indexes, so sorting `i` does fix the problem.

However due to the fact that `std::vector` is a contiguous array, erasing elements one by one is usually not a very good idea. In your case, it's fairly easy to rearrange the code to do all the erasing in one go:

```
std::sort(i.begin(),i.end());
i.push_back(s.size()); //just to make sure the whole vector is visited
auto iter = s.begin();
int current_index = 0;
for(int index : i)
{
    while(current_index < index)
    {
        *(iter++) = s[current_index++];
    }
    current_index++;
}
s.erase(iter, s.end());
```

In case you can afford to represent the elements to be deleted by a certain value, e.g. an empty string, it gets better:

```
for(int index : i)
    s[index] = "";
s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(),s.end(),""),s.end());
```